# Measured foliations on surfaces

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, ergodic-theory, foliations

Is the measure of a simple closed curve consisting of two arcs transversal to a foliation equal to the sum of the measures of these arcs? Let A be an arc that is the union of arcs B and C, where arc B is transversal to the foliation and arc C is contained in a leaf of the foliation. Is the measure of arc A equal to the measure of arc B? Is the measure of open arc equal to its closure?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check Ivanov's book on subgroups of the mapping class group?

Comment: But what else would you like to learn about measured foliations?

Comment: I think there's no books describing $\mathcal{MF}$ more detailed than FLP.   Combinatorics of train tracks by Penner and Haar,  Train Track Expansions of Measured Foliations by Moser are other two books on $\mathcal{MF}$.

Comment: Can you be more specific and focussed regarding which *more detail*s you are concerned about? As said by @gaoqiang, there are few other books, but on the other hand the published literature has lots of papers covering different sub-topics within measured foliations. A more focussed question from you could result in good references.

Comment: @LeeMosher I would like to understand, for example, Is the measure of a simple closed curve consisting of two arcs transversal to a foliation equal to the sum of the measures of these arcs? Let A be an arc that is the union of arcs B and C, where arc B is transversal to the foliation and arc C is contained in a leaf of the foliation. Is the measure of arc A equal to the measure of arc B? Is the measure of open arc equal to its closure? I suppose that it is all too obvious but I have some doubts.

Comment: That's a good question. Let me suggest, though, that rather then having a discussion in comments (which is not proper for MSE; see [the tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)), you instead edit your post to state a specific question like this, so that someone can give a proper answer to it.

Comment: It seems that your problem is not with measured foliations but with the definition of a measure. Do you know the additivity property of measures?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes, i know.

Comment: Then I do not understand why are you asking about additivity in this special case.